# Where is the Correct Plugin Location for Winforms

Tags: windows, winforms

I have an a Winform Application and it can accept plugins (created either by us or by the user).
Under Windows 7 or later, where is the correct place to put the plugins,

- ...\ProgramData\CoName\Application\Plugins
- ...\Program Files\CoName\Application\Plugins

Thanks
JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anywhere you want, depending on your needs. `Program Files` is by default (since Windows Vista if I recall correctly) only accessible to administrators, so if you need to write there without being an administrator, use `ProgramData` (or any other folder you prefer)

Comment: But shouldn't ProgramData be used solely for data?
Does windows allow executables to run from there?
Putting the DLLs in ProgramData, does it pass windows certification?

Comment: A plugin is "data" also, so it's ok to have it there... there's no problem running DLL code from anywhere as long as the user has permission to read that DLL. About Windows Certification, I wouldn't know, I've never certified any program, but if you are worried about Windows Certification, you should ask Microsoft for it.

Comment: Actually a plugin is a DLL with executable data in it following a pre-defined interface, so theoretically it is an executable.
On the other had, it cannot be run on its own, but from another program running from the Program Files directory.
Currently, Windows allows any executable to be installed and run in the ProgramData directory, even if you're not an Administrator.

Comment: @Jean-PierreScerri I know what a DLL is... but data is data: whether that data are bytecodes that can be run by your processor, or a series of bytes that represent an image, or whatever else, it's still data used by your program, so in my dictionary, it falls under "program data" (as in language, not as in the folder). If you don't think it does, then create whatever folder you need and point to that folder, or let the plugin installer create their own folder, and have them register in your application (via the registry or whatever).